# Is it possible to fit a Keras model via CPU multiprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, model-fitting

Is it possible to fit a Keras model via multiprocessing on 4 CPUs? (no GPUs)
If so, how to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Keras will try and fit your model in parallel (multiprocessing) using all the cores available on your machine.
You can choose the number of cpus (or jobs) using this snippet:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
jobs = 4 # number of cores
config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=jobs,
                     inter_op_parallelism_threads=jobs,
                     allow_soft_placement=True,
                     device_count={'CPU': jobs})
session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

Comment: `Thx, I work with model = keras...Sequential(). how can I integrate this into the model.fit() function?

Comment: The code snippet should work for any keras api you use. Just past the snippet code at the start of your program and you are good to go :)